# Can I style the SurveyJs forms with tailwind css?

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, surveyjs

I don't know how to style the SurveyJs elements via Tailwind CSS. Can anyone guide me please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a new object with all classes. For example:

```
const cssClasses = {
  footer: "sv_nav mt-10 flex justify-between",
  imagepicker: {
    item: "sv_q_imgsel w-full inline-block !mr-0 max-w-[10rem] text-center",
    image:
      "sv_image_image w-20 h-20 rounded-full bg-[#e0cfc7] checked:bg-[#e78370] mx-auto mt-3",
    root: "sv_imagesel flex flex-wrap justify-center",
    label: "sv_q_imgsel_label children:!border-0",
    itemInline: "sv_q_imagepicker_inline grow shrink basis-1/3 !leading-6",
    itemText: "sv_q_imgsel_text !break-normal !whitespace-normal",
    itemControl: "sv_q_imgsel_control_item hidden",
    mainRoot:
      "sv_q sv_qstn py-4 px-4 mt-3 border-b border-[#ddd] flex flex-col",
    itemChecked: "sd-imagepicker__item--checked checked",
    checkedItemDecorator: "hidden",
  },
  radiogroup: {
    label:
      "sv_q_radiogroup_label justify-left inline-block text-center border border-[#ccc] rounded-md w-full cursor-pointer p-2.5 checked:bg-primary checked:text-white",
    itemControl: "sv_q_radiogroup_control_item hidden",
    item: "sv_q_radiogroup w-full pr-2.5 max-w-[6.875rem] mb-4 mt-2 inline-block",
    root: "sv_qcbc text-center mt-2.5",
    itemChecked: "sd-item--checked sd-radio--checked checked",
  }
};
```

2. Attach this object to the Survey instance -

```
const survey = new Model(surveyJson);
survey.css = cssClasses;
```

To look at the full object with all available keys you can just do

```
const survey = new Model(surveyJson);
console.log(survey.css);
```

And in your override object, you don't have define all keys. Only the ones you define will be overwritten. I found this to be a better method than overwriting the classes in the base tailwind css file. Much cleaner.